# Nesting liquid tag to select a list item

Tags: email, shopify, liquid, mailchimp

Hey I'm wondering if you could help me with some Liquid coding I am struggling with.

I am using Liquid with customer.io in order to code an email template.

customer.io uses data from user attributes e.g `{{customer.sub_speciality_id}}`
as well as data from a trigger sent as a JSON e.g `{{trigger.test}}`

I am using the following tag `{{trigger.sub_specialities.3[0].title}}`

Which looks in the JSON under for the values from the key "sub_specialities" it then chooses the section whose key is "3" which is a list, then picks the first item in that list and returns the title

That works fine.

But what I would like to do is to replace `3` with a liquid tag based off the customer attribute `sub_speciality` which is stored as `{{customer.sub_speciality_id}}`

so in a way `{{trigger.sub_specialities.{{customer.sub_speciality_id}}[0].title}}`

But I know you can't do liquid like that. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Will something like this not work `{{trigger.sub_specialities[customer.sub_speciality_id][0].title}}` ?

Comment: @drip that was my guess but I get `Variable 'trigger.sub_specialities[customer.sub_speciality_id][0].title' is missing
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert that key to string, like this `{{trigger.sub_specialities["3"][0].title}}`
I use a [capture](https://customer.io/docs/liquid-tag-list/#capture) tag from Liquid to capture value.

```
{% capture sub_speciality_id %}{{customer.sub_speciality_id}}{% endcapture %}
```

When I capture that value in variable `sub_speciality_id` I can use that to retrieve data.

```
{{trigger.sub_specialities[sub_speciality_id][0].title}}
```